# Are there words other than "friend" where "ie" is pronounced as /ɛ/ ("short e")?

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling, vowels

Are there any words in English other than *friend* where the spelling "ie" corresponds to the "short e" sound /ɛ/?

Comment: Not any common ones that I can think of, other than ones containing *friend*, such as  *friends*, *friendly*, *friendship*, *girlfriend*, *boyfriend*, etc. Wikipedia gives ***hygienic***. I guess you could try recall your *hygienic friend*.

Comment: To emphasize what @sumelic asked, do you mean same -spelling- as friend or same pronunciation? There are lots of words that rhyme with 'friend' but spell the vowel differently.

Comment: @sumelic &Mitch. Yes. Words with 'ie'  that are pronounced with short /e/ like 'friend'.

Comment: A lot of people pronounce friend with a *short I*, as in: **frinned**.

Comment: @Bread: do you mean as a special pronunciation just for this word, or are you talking about accents where “pen” is likewise pronounced as “pin”?

Comment: @sumelic ~ just friend. However the short e and short i sounds are often pronounced interchangeably, depending on the surrounding consonants and other factors. In fact, it is probably the consonant **n** which causes the problem with both friend and pen.

Answer (score 1):

Not any common words other than ones containing *friend*, such as

*friends*
*friendly*
*friendship*
*befriend*
*unfriend*
*girlfriend*
*boyfriend*

the open compounds
*girl friend*
*boy friend*, etc.

Wikipedia supplies

*hygienic*.

I guess you could try to recall if your friend is hygienic. Otherwise, a *friend* stays until the *end*. There is also the surname

*Friend*

as in the baseball player *Bob Friend*.

Comment: I don't really buy the *hygienic* example. Etymologically, that <i> represents /j/ (the sound of <y> in *yes*); it's merely coalesced into the preceding consonant, making it effectively silent. If anything, we should say that the <gi> represents /dʒ/ (the sound of <j> in *job*), like the <gi> in *region*, *allegiance*, *collegial* / *collegiate*, *theologian*, *religious*, etc. (The only difference is that those words still need the <i> to keep the <g> from being pronounced /g/, whereas *hygienic* could now be spelled as <hygenic> without affecting its pronunciation.)

Comment: @ruakh: "hygiene" and "hygienic" have weird pronunciations. (I asked a [question about it on Linguistics SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/19270)). Normally, an "i" in this position that is not interpreted as part of a digraph, but as a "weak" reduced vowel or glide (/i~j/) would be expected to have a syllabic pronunciation because of the stress on the following syllable (compare *religiosity,* which isn't typically pronounced "relijosity"), and the preceding syllable would be expected not to have a "long i" sound (/ai/). That is, we'd expect the pronunciation /ˌhɪdʒiˈɛnɪk/.

Comment: @sumelic: Hmm, I see what you mean. Still, since etymological /dʒj/ regularly becomes /dʒ/ (as in my previous examples, as well as in the stressed syllables of words like *jury*, *injurious*, *Jew*, *June*, *jewel*), I think the pronunciation of *hygienic* is close-enough-to-regular that we can comfortably identify the <i> as having been absorbed into the /dʒ/ and become silent, rather than somehow merging into the /ɛ/.

Answer (score 1):

#### *Lieutenant* (in British English)?

A British English pronunciation of the word *[lieutenant](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/lieutenant)* starts with /lɛ/: Collins gives "lɛfˈtɛnənt". This could be seen as a word where "ie" = /ɛ/. But this correspondence is not present for the American English speakers who use the pronunciation " luːˈtɛnənt".

#### *Hemielytron* (in American English)?

I think it's just a mistake, but the Collins website gives "hɛˈmɛlɪˌtrɑn" as the American English pronunciation of "[hemielytron](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hemielytron)", and defines it as

> *alt. sp. of* hemelytron

Personally, I would always associate the alternative spelling *hemielytron* with the alternative pronunciation /ˌhɛmɪˈɛlɪˌtrɑn/, but it's not a word that I use, so I can't say for sure whether anybody uses the spelling "hemielytron" and the pronunciation "hɛˈmɛlɪˌtrɑn" the way that Collins suggests.